# A problem with Arduino

Tags: 14.04, arduino

I have Arduino uno.
I connected it my My Laptop " Ubuntu 14.04.02".
but when i go to Tool , Serial Port is unavailable.
I dont know why ?
Is there any command should i write in Terminal to run ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use it you must have permissions. Usually arduino is recognized as tty port, so just typing these commands should be fine:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty yourUserName

sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName
```

After that, your user will have enough permissions to use Arduino. Just log off and log in again.

Comment: @Yusuf, you are welcome. Hope that works out for you.